# A case of undefined behaviour when using a union

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have the following code coming from the book "C++17 in detail" :

```
union Superfloat{
float f;
int i;
}

int RawMantissa(Superfloat f){
return f.i & ((1< 23) -1);
}

int RawExponent(Superfloat f){
return (f.i >> 23)& 0xFF;
}
```

After that code, Mr Bartlomiej Filipek writes :
"However, while the above code might work in C99, due to stricter alising rules it's undefined behaviour in C++".

I would like to understand better what the author means by that sentence, because I don't understand it.
Could you explain to me in details ?

He gives the following explanation (but I need more explanations) :

> C.183!... it is undefined to read a union member with a different type from the one with which it was written. Such punning is invisible, or at least harder to spot than using a named >cast.....

I don't understand that explanation too, and how it helps to understand that the code above is undefined behaviour.

I would be thankful for your deep explanations

Comment: You seem to be leaving out something important in that code snippet. None of it is undefined behavior in itself. It depends on how the union passed to it was initialized, etc. I assume the original example calls the functions with a union with active `f` member.

Comment: What's unclear about *it is undefined to read a union member with a different type*?  In C++ you can't just read from the inactive member of a union.

Comment: `Superfloat sf;  sf.f = 10.f; RawMantissa(sf);` would be UB becase you set `f` but read `i`.

Comment: I would recommend watching this CppCon video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc The speaker explains everything with great attention to the detail and proposes more modern solutions.

Comment: In your title, please actually summarise the question. Don't just list a bunch of terms...

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty simple. A union has at most one member active. A member becomes active when you write to it. You can only read from the active member.

Example:

```
union U
{
    float f;
    int i;
};

auto foo_1()
{
    U u; // no member is active

    u.f = 24.5; // write to `u.f` . `u.f` is now the active member

    int i = u.i; // read of `u.i` Since `u.i` is not the active member this is UB in C++
}
```

```
auto foo_2()
{
    U u;
    // no active member

    u.f = 24.5; // write to `u.f` . `u.f` is now the active member

    float f = u.f; // read of `u.f` . Ok since `u.f` is the active member

    u.i = 11; // write to `u.i` . `u.i` is now the active member.
              // `u.f` is NOT the active member anymore

    int i = u.i; // ok, read of the active member `u.i`

    float f2 = u.f; // read of `u.f`. UB, since `u.f` is not the active member
}
```

Comment: Also, only direct assignment as you show here counts as "write" to establish the active member. Writing e.g. through a reference to the non-active member is not allowed, I think.

Comment: @walnut it is allowed. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: The [relevant standard paragraph](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#union-6) describes the structure of an assignment activating a member explicitly and it does not apply to assignment through a reference.

Comment: @walnut I don't see how that rules out your case. We simply fall through to the third case/bullet - _S(e)_ is empty, which indeed it is if your left-hand operand is simply a single name `nameOfReferenceToUnionMember`. Can you expand on why you think that section rules out assignment through a reference to the union member?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica The first sentence requires a member access operator to be present on the left-hand side of the assignment and if the set is empty then "*for each element X of S(E1), [...] an object of the type of X is implicitly created in the nominated storage*" wouldn't create any object and hence not change any active member. (That was my reading of it.)

Comment: @walnut Oh, I see. Is it a stretch to say that the left operand "involves" a member access because you had to use one to procure the operand? :)

Comment: I like how (6.2) is basically just a workaround for the validity of `0[array]` :D

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I suppose every reference to an expression of the form `A[B]` in the standard must consider both orders of operands. I am still not sure whether there ever was a valid reason for allowing that syntax aside from code obfuscation.

Comment: @walnut It's just a consequence of how it's defined and it may have been excessively complicated to come up with strong wording that bans specifically `0[array]` without accidentally banning anything more useful. I don't think I've ever seen anywhere apart from 6.2 that had to "undo" it, so it was probably the right choice

Comment: @bolov, thank you for your help.    3 questions : 1) Does that mean that the code provided by the book does not display the problem , because this code is not UB ?      2) If you activate the different members in different functions, it is valid , I guess ?     3) Could you please , write an example of code , based on the snippet i have provided , which is REALLY UB     ? thank you

Comment: @Dev using functions changes nothing. The "at most one member active" doesn't apply to functions or scopes. It's per object.

Comment: @Dev: The C Standard was written with the intention that if parts of the Standard and an implementation's documentation described the behavior of a construct, but other parts characterized it as UB, implementations would behave as described *when useful and practical* without regard for whether the Standard required them to do so.  The C++ Standard has tried to fill in many such holes, but never in ways that would avoid interfering with anything programmers needed to do.